# Crawler not crawling just a few pages, crawls everything else

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

I have the crawler setup in my app and it works great, but have an issue with just couple urls. It does not crawl these pages, the only difference I see between these couple pages and other pages which are crawled is these have a lot of sub links on these pages, about 800-1000.

Can you please help, with any settings that I can update to see if these would get crawled.

I am using the crawler which is compatible with ES 5.6.3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of the config *http.content.limit*, its value is set to *65536* in the archetype. This could explain why you are missing outlinks on the larger documents. Setting it to -1 would guarantee that the whole document is processed, regardless of its size.

Comment: I had that set at http.content.limit: 52428800, and I updated that to -1, still it does not crawl. It does add that to status index i.e. it is discovered, but then it does nothing with the crawl command. I have this added in crawler-conf.

Comment: I changed a few other options and it worked. Thanks Julien.

Comment: @heythere what were these options? if the URLs are added to the status index, they should get fetched sooner or later.